# Fast frame extraction from mp4 files on UWP

Tags: uwp, windows-runtime, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I am trying to extract and analyze mp4 files faster than realtime as I do not need every single frame.

I have tried following:

```
composition.GetThumbnailAsync(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(i),160,90,VideoFramePrecision.NearestKeyFrame);
```

which gave me about 1fps before any processing.

```
mediaPlayer.PlaybackSession.PlaybackRate = x;
```

where x would work differently for each video; sometimes would play smooth 60fps playback up to x=2, but on other that would result in 1 fps.

The best results were with
MediaPlayer setting `mediaPlayer.IsVideoFrameServerEnabled = true;`
with `mediaPlayer.StepForwardOneFrame();` in `mediaPlayer_VideoFrameAvailable`

That would ensure all next frames arrived after each one is actually done (so better or worse depending on file), but that is still wasting resources as I am getting each frame, and need every >5th frame.

I think it is all related to Keyframes or "I" frames in video but I don't see that there is a way to get those only.

Any ideas on getting frames faster while skipping n frames at a time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn’t a more efficient way to get every nth frame. You could set the Position to every nth frame but the seeking algorithm searches for the closest previous keyframe and then decodes from there. Because of this you may be decoding more frames by setting the Position. So you may be saving time decoding every frame via frame step. There is no easy way using the MediaPlayer to seek to a keyframe. You would need to parse the h.264 file to get the keyframe distance and then you could set the position to this cadence.